# how is possible to change not nested elements attribute with css?

Tags: html, css

is it possible to do something like this with css without javascript?
assume that i have to div that are not nested. i want to change one's attributes when i click on the other one.

for example:

```
<div class="1"> first div </div>
<div class="2"> second div </div>
```

i want when i click on div 1 the second div appear or it's font color change to another color.

i've tested this code but it works when divs are nested:

```
.1:hover .2{ font-size:16px; }
```

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `+` (next sibling selector) or `~` (following sibling).  I'm not sure that `1` and `2` are valid class names, though.

```
.one:hover + .two
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Unjh/

This is also not directly related to clicking, just hovering.  For clicking a non-semantic solution using only CSS/HTML with inputs that can be toggled is possible.

```
:checked + .two

<label for=check> first div </label><input hidden type=checkbox id=check>
<div class=two>second div</div>
```

Comment: thakyou. how can i do this with clicking?